# Python error "ascii codec cannot encode character..."

Tags: python, unicode

I have a script which shows

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u044e' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

for line `print ord(u), u`. How can I run the script ok?

I run `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe name.py`.

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
print "Russian letters".center(18*4)
i = 0
for c in "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"\
         "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя":
  u = unicode(c, 'koi8-r')  
  print ord(u), u
  i += 1
  if i % 4 == 0:
    print
```

Comment: I just tried this script and it worked for me. What version of Python are you running?

Comment: Py2.7. File is UTF8. Win XP.

Comment: @skishore it work but it raise exception at the begining, try `> /dev/null` to see error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot print a unicode charater to the windows console if the local encoding doesn't support it. So python tries to encode it as `ascii` and fails. The problematic line is:

```
print ord(u), u
```

`u` is a unicode character. What you want is probably:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

print "Russian letters".center(18*4)
i = 0
for c in u"АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"\
         u"абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя":
    u = c.encode('koi8-r')  
    print ord(u), u
    i += 1
    if i % 4 == 0:
        print
```

Also use `python.exe` for console applications, not `pythonw.exe`